# Calculate angle of rotation

Tags: c++, rotation, geometry

I have a rectangle on the scene and I want to rotate it with mouse.
The rectangle has his own origin point. Clicking on the scene represents start of rotation and mouse moving represent angle of rotation.

[image]

where:

- O - origin of rotation point
- A - anchor point (saved in OnMousePress event)
- C - current point (from OnMouseMove event)

so I calculate the angle in next steps:

Fistly, I get lengths of triangle sides:

```
AO = sqrt( (O.x - A.x)^2 + (O.y - A.y)^2 )

CO = sqrt( (O.x - C.x)^2 + (O.y - C.y)^2 )

AC = sqrt( (C.x - A.x)^2 + (C.y - A.y)^2 )
```

and then I calculate the angle (a):

`a = arccos ( (AO^2 + CO^2 - AC^2) / (2 * AO * CO) )`

it works, but this calculation look too complicated taking into account that I need to repeat on it all OnMouseMove call.

So my question - is there another way to calculate the angle? I write it in c++ so some code snippet will be apprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find angle between vectors **OA** and **OC** through their scalar product and cross product:

```
OA = (OA.X, OA.Y) = (A.X-O.X, A.Y-O.Y)
OC = (OC.X, OC.Y) = (C.X-O.X, C.Y-O.Y)
SP = OA * OC = OA.X*OC.X+OA.Y*OC.Y
CP = OA x OC = OA.X*OC.Y-OA.Y*OC.X
Angle = atan2(CP, SP)
```

Example: O = (0,0), A = (-1, 0), C = (-2, 1)
  SP = 2, CP = -1, Angle = -0.463

This method allows to avoid sqrt calculations, and determines rotation direction (unlike arccos)

Answer (score 1):

You use a dot product of vectors OA and OC divided by their magnitude to calculate cosine of the angle and then use `acos()` function to find the angle.

```
float cosAngle = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) * sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
float angle = acos(cosAngle);
```